# Where's the line between "Asking for a software recommendation" and "How to file taxes for my state"?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, off-topic

I think clearly off-topic: "What's the best tax software to use?" (While many things here are opinion-based to some degree, this is a "shopping" question that's not really going to have a useful "correct" long-lived answer.)

I think clearly on-topic: "What are the filing methods $State allows for my state taxes?" (It's answerable, can likely use the state's web site or official form instructions as references, and will have as long-lived an answer as anything related to taxes can.)

The question that brings this up: [Is there a “Free File Fillable Forms” equivalent for CA Form 540 for California Income tax?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/78596/42405)

My thinking is that it's much closer to my second example than my first. It's asking about filing directly with the questioner's state, and what options the state offers. A moderator closed the question as "seeking product or service recommendations". I can certainly understand where he's coming from, as it could be close to my first example, and could go in that direction if answerers aren't careful, but I think it's still on the "on-topic" side of the line. I submitted a flag for moderator review to re-open, and the moderator replied "I think those are still off-topic. Maybe open a question on meta?"

And thus, I'm opening a question on meta to discuss this. At what point does asking about how to file ones taxes turn into a "service recommendation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I closed it, in response, and agreement with a flag-to-close. And another mod agreed with me, rejecting your flag-to-reopen.

There are now 4 reopen votes, and one more will open it. My gut reaction is that nothing is free, and if the form isn't in-your-face on the state website, then it's a company that providing it 'free' in return for the State and IRS not entering into the tax software business. I agree, this is a gray area, and if voted to reopen, it will stay open.

Edit - I just saw the referenced question is now re-opened. I see the posted answer is basically 'no'. Either way, it will stay open.